# How write Excel Table's cell value to a Txt file using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I´m trying to create a CSV file that will export an Excel Table Column Cell Values, in the following manner:

```
row number "Tab" cell values
```

but in the following script it only exports the value of the first cell in the table (the rows number & order is correct) .. How to fix it ?

```
Private Sub ExportAsCSV()
'Export current sheet as a CSV TXT file on the same location

Dim ThisPathName, CSVFileName, ThisFileName, ThisSheetName As String
Dim SeriesRange As Range
Dim i As Integer

ThisPathName = ThisWorkbook.Path                        ' Generate workbook current path
ThisFileName = ThisPathName & "/" & ThisWorkbook.Name   ' Generate file name & path
ThisSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name                        ' Generate sheet name

CSVFileName = ThisPathName & "/Wren Kitchens " & ThisSheetName & ".txt"
' Sets CSV txt file name and location

If ActiveSheet.Name = "00 Kitchen Series" Then
    'if active table is "00 Kitchen Series"

    Open CSVFileName For Output As #1

    Set SeriesRange = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("KitchenLinesTable").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    
    For i = 1 To SeriesRange.Count
        Print #1, i & "   " & ActiveSheet.ListObjects("KitchenLinesTable").DataBodyRange(1, i).Value
    Next i

    Close #1
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Do you want copying a row or a column?

Comment: Try changing of `DataBodyRange(1, i).Value` with `DataBodyRange(i, 1).Value`, You must iterate **on rows**...

Comment: @FaneDuru Thank you it works. Although this is my 3rd day working with VBA, I feel stupid for this type of error

Comment: Glad I could help! Now, I will try posting an answer using a compact way to create the string to be placed in the csv file. I would like you to try understanding it... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next compact way to create the CSV string:

Replace this code:

```
If ActiveSheet.Name = "00 Kitchen Series" Then
    'if active table is "00 Kitchen Series"

    Open CSVFileName For Output As #1

    Set SeriesRange = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("KitchenLinesTable").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    
    For i = 1 To SeriesRange.Count
        Print #1, i & "   " & ActiveSheet.ListObjects("KitchenLinesTable").DataBodyRange(i, 1).Value
    Next i

    Close #1
    End If
End Sub
```

with the next one:

```
    Set SeriesRange = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("KitchenLinesTable").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    Open CSVFileName For Output As #1
        Print #1, Join(Application.Transpose(Evaluate("row(1:" & SeriesRange.count & ")&""    ""&" & SeriesRange.Address)), vbCrLf)
    Close #1
```

The arrays VBA part and `Evaluate` method can be something amazing, if you understand them... I will try showing what is necessary to be known, in order o understand the above code. Open Immediate Window `(`Ctrl + G`, being in VBE) and press` F5`when code stops (on`Stop` command) and could see the return:

```
Sub TestToUnderstandAboveCode()
    Dim SeriesRange As Range
    Set SeriesRange = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("KitchenLinesTable").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    
    '1. Placing a range in an array:
    Dim arr: arr = SeriesRange.Value 'it creates a 2D array
          Debug.Print arr(1, 1)      'returns the first array element
    'Make the above array 1D:
    arr = Application.Transpose(arr)
       'or doing it dirrectly:
       arr = Application.Transpose(SeriesRange.Value)
       'it can be tested so:
       Debug.Print Join(arr, "|")
       'another way to create an array is using Evaluate (very powerfull method):
       arr = Evaluate(SeriesRange.Address)                                '2D array
       arr = Application.Transpose(Evaluate(SeriesRange.Address)) '1D array
       Debug.Print Join(arr, "|"): Stop 'it returns the same as above. Press F5 to continue the code
       
    'now we need to  build another 1D array to keep the range rows:
    Dim arrRows: arrRows = Application.Evaluate("row(1:10)") '2D array keeping numbers from 1 to 10
      Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(arrRows), "|")  'You can join only a 1D array to see the jonned string
      'Now, let us personalize it according to the necessary string to be processed:
      arrRows = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("row(1:" & SeriesRange.cells.count & ")"))
      Debug.Print Join(arrRows, "|")
      
     'Now, putting all pieces together:
     arr = Evaluate("row(1:" & SeriesRange.count & ")&""    ""&" & SeriesRange.Address) 'it creates a 2D array separating arrays by "   "
        Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(arr), "|") ': Stop
       'having a 1D array and needing a string having end lines for each array element we need to build it
       'for doing it we need to firstly join the array elements by vbCrLf (end of line) separator:
       Dim strArr As String
         strArr = Join(Application.Transpose(arr), vbCrLf)
         Debug.Print strArr : Stop 'it returns the string showing all elemnts one bellow the other.
       'and finally doit it at once:
       strArr = Join(Application.Transpose(Evaluate("row(1:" & SeriesRange.count & ")&""    ""&" & SeriesRange.Address)), vbCrLf)
       Debug.Print strArr
End Sub
```

Comment: @Nader Belal Did you understand the logic of the code?

Answer (score 1):

Hi here is my generic Sub to export a CSV file inside a folder in the same directory as the workbook, you juste have to send the table name when you call it

```
ExportTableToCSV("MyTableName")
```

And it call the following sub

```
Public Sub ExportTableToCSV(TableName as String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FilePath, CSVLocation, fol As String
    Dim ParseRange As Range
    Dim cellValue As Variant
    Dim j, k As Integer

    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
    Set ParseRange = ws.ListObjects(TableName).Range
    
    CSVLocation = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\NewFolder\"
    fol = Dir(CSVLocation, vbDirectory)
    If fol = "" Then MkDir CSVLocation
    
    FilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\NewFolder\" & TableName & ".csv"
    
    Open FilePath For Output As #1
    For j = 1 To ParseRange.Rows.Count
        For k = 1 To ParseRange.Columns.Count
            cellValue = ParseRange.Cells(j, k).Value
            If k = ParseRange.Columns.Count Then
                Write #1, cellValue
            Else
                Write #1, cellValue,
            End If
        Next k
    Next j
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @FaneDuru for the answer s/he have provided in the comments.

The problem was caused by `DataBodyRange(1, i).Value`, as Excel understands that it's iterating by the table's rows.

The correct answer must be `DataBodyRange(i, 1).Value`, so that Excel can iterate by row's indices.

The code corrected:

```
Private Sub ExportAsCSV()
'Export current sheet as a CSV TXT file on the same location

Dim ThisPathName, CSVFileName, ThisFileName, ThisSheetName As String
Dim SeriesRange As Range
Dim i As Integer

ThisPathName = ThisWorkbook.Path                        ' Generate workbook current path
ThisFileName = ThisPathName & "/" & ThisWorkbook.Name   ' Generate file name & path
ThisSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name                        ' Generate sheet name

CSVFileName = ThisPathName & "/Wren Kitchens " & ThisSheetName & ".txt"
' Sets CSV txt file name and location

If ActiveSheet.Name = "00 Kitchen Series" Then
    'if active table is "00 Kitchen Series"

    Open CSVFileName For Output As #1

    Set SeriesRange = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("KitchenLinesTable").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    
    For i = 1 To SeriesRange.Count
        Print #1, i & "   " & ActiveSheet.ListObjects("KitchenLinesTable").DataBodyRange(i, 1).Value
    Next i

    Close #1
    End If
End Sub
```

Once again, Thank you @FaneDuru